# nginx docker-image not reachable

Tags: nginx, docker

I am new to docker and I have problems to get nginx running.
It all seems correct. nginx is reachable from the host using "curl".
iptables sets up a new rule for docker virtual interface.

But nginx is not reachable from the internet.

I am using a debian (jessie)

```
Linux h2127057 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

docker is version

```
Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e
```

netstat is giving

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:514             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0    216 X.X.X.X:22              X.X.X.X:64103      VERBUNDEN  
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::514                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

iptables rules as followed

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION
-N fail2ban-pam-generic
-N fail2ban-ssh
-N fail2ban-ssh-ddos
-A FORWARD -d 172.24.18.12/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 172.24.18.12/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 172.24.18.12/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 172.24.18.12/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 172.24.18.12/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 172.24.18.12/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 172.24.18.12/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

As you can see there are already rules on another subnet. This is my old virtual infrastructure using plain LXC.

Can this makes me getting problems ?

Thank you all for helping
David

Comment: But if your app is visible on host, on a specific port then all you need to do is to open this port (on host) to the world, and eventually add domain to etc/hosts as well. IMO there is nothing more to make with docker itself.

Comment: here is how i expose the ports to the machine
`docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 nginx`

Comment: so now it seems that you have some kind of router/firewall/whatever what blocks incoming port 80/443 trafic from internet to your host.
You need to search for guide how to open ports on your OS/router. If on host you see nginx served page by going to localhost:80, then after opening ports it will be reachable from YOUREXTERNALIP:80 (or somedomain.tld if you add it to your etc/hosts like 127.0.0.1 somedomain.tld)

Comment: and this is what makes me struggle:
i can easily run an old lxc container with a webserver and it will be reachable without problems...

Comment: still not working with ip/domain entry in etc/hosts :-(

Comment: hmm ... weird ... can you try with --net=host ? besides that I don't have an idea now, docker for mac (which I'm using) works ok (but it may be because it's docker inside vm).

Comment: really weird :-( option --net=host doesn't work either.
Maybe there is a collision between the internal processes? because i am using LXC and docker on the same machine?

Comment: can you stop containers (LXC, docker), install eg. apache locally (just to see welcome page on :80) and see if you can reach it from outside? If not, then there are some firewall rules which works nicely with LXC (for some reason) but not with other services ...

Comment: this helped a bit, unless i do not understand this behavior. i stopped all containers (LXC and docker) and installed nginx on the host.
first it seems not to work, but after binding the hosts IP to iptables FORWARD chain it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's come to a first conclusion:

I have no problems running a webserver within an LXC container and using iptables for port-forwarding. Everything works fine. Great working!

If I try the same with docker the webserver is not reachable from outside, even if iptables is set up properly and docker is exposing the ports. Not working!

Stopping all containers (LXC and docker) and running a bare-metal webserver it needs to specify a rule in iptables that points to the outer IP address. Than it will be reachable from the internet.

So why does everything works as it should, except the docker-nginx-image?

Very strange :-(

EDIT:
Okay, i have it!! After killing all LXC and docker containers, flushing iptables AND stopping fail2ban!! it all works as it should. Even if starting fail2ban after all...

This means for me: Let docker manage all iptables-rules for you. I am not deep enough in iptables, but if you have a FORWARD chain "before" your DOCKER chain it makes problems.